Error: Job for telegraf.service failed because the control process exited with error code
I have already installed InfluxDB on my Ubuntu instance. After that, I installed Telegraf. But when I checked the status of Telegraf, it said: Failed to Start Telegraf
See below image for better understanding.

When i run systemctl start telegraf command then it gives this output:

Job for telegraf.service failed because the control process exited
with error code. See "systemctl status telegraf.service" and
"journalctl -xe" for details.

Here are the installation commands for Telegraf that i executed:
curl -s https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdata-archive.key > influxdata-archive.key
echo '943666881a1b8d9b849b74caebf02d3465d6beb716510d86a39f6c8e8dac7515 influxdata-archive.key' | sha256sum -c && cat influxdata-archive.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive.gpg > /dev/null
echo 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/debian stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdata.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install telegraf

which is as per official documentation.
this is the logs that might help:

Now, how can I start the Telegraf service? I need it to run and export my metrics to InfluxDB.

After a lot of effort, I found that after installing Telegraf, I started the Telegraf service without changing the Telegraf configuration. That's why this error is occurring.
Also check these points:

Sometimes this error occurs when there is a problem in the configuration file. Some configuration elements you are using are deprecated, so make sure to check that too.

You can check logs telegraf using this command: sudo tail -f /var/log/telegraf/telegraf.log.
By checking these logs, you can identify which errors are occurring.

You can check if the syntax of a Telegraf config file is valid by using this command. telegraf --config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf --test


TLDR: Change the Telegraf config file first, then execute this command: systemctl start telegraf
